# Blocking access to Application When User leaves the company

Tags: iphone

I am building an app which will be distributed using enterprise distribution.So we need to disable the app whenever the user leaves the company.
I can have a web service through which I can check the status of user.
What would be a nice way to disable the app.Should I stop loading my root view or should I present a modal view saying that app has been disabled.
Could someone suggest a nice way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple view to inform the user the app has been disabled is the most appropriate.  Remember to delete any data that may have been cached on the phone also.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, when the application loads, it can send in a check to determine whether or not the person is still in the database.  This is simple and effective.

Comment: But once I know that user is not there.How should I disable the application on phone.